# Image Age Information of XYZ Base Map in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, date

Is there a way to find the age of the imagery of a base map via pyqgis? Any help on this would be much appreciated.Thanks.

[image: Bing Satellite Map Properties in QGIS]